# Convert sql query to ORM Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I have a function in a model file for the ODOO framework. I just came across SQL queries within my functions. I just want to convert the SQL query to ORM with Odoo framework.
Like, create, search, browse inbuilt functions that it already has. I just need some examples for the two queries I have in the below function like how we convert it to ORM with GOOD explanation. so that I can carry forward the same with other queries as well.

Function:

```
def bill(self,data):

    id = data.get('id', False)
    if data:
        chge = []
        s_Date = data['start_date']
        e_Date = data['end_date']
        query = """SELECT "endpoll","table_name","kcp","plan","startpoll",id FROM 
        bill WHERE ((("endpoll" >= '%s')  OR  "endpoll" IS NULL )  AND  ("startpoll" <= '%s')  AND  
        ("customer" = %s)  AND  ("active" in ('Y','N'))) ORDER BY "startpoll" """ % (
        s_Date, e_Date, id)
        self._cr.execute(query)
        status_records = self._cr.dictfetchall()
        if not status_records:
            return []
        gst = 0
        for records in status_records:
            icp_id = record['ikp']
            varcharge = 0
            query2 = """SELECT "read_date" FROM dailycharges WHERE (("billstatus" = %s)  
            AND  ("status" = 'B')) ORDER BY "read_date" desc limit 1""" % (
                record['id'])
            self._cr.execute(query2)
            maxbill = self._cr.fetchone()
            if maxbill:
                unbill = datetime.strptime(maxbill[0]

            else:
                unbill = record['Start_Date']
            start_date = max(invoice_start_date, str(unbill))

    return data
```

There are two simple queries within this function. I need them to be converted into ORM. Thanks in advance.

Comment: They could be replaced with the `search` method. `WHERE` clause will be converted to a [search domain](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#search-domains), `ORDER BY` will be replaced with `order` parameter (`order='read_date desc'`) and the `LIMIT` clause is available as parameter (`limit='1'`).

Comment: @Kenly Can you please make it as a query in a single line if possible.?

Comment: We need definitions for bill and dailycharges models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could be replaced with the `search` method. `WHERE` clause will be converted to a [search domain](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#search-domains), `ORDER` BY will be replaced with order parameter (`order='read_date desc'`) and the `LIMIT` clause is available as a parameter (`limit='1'`).

For example, the second select query could be replaced with:

```
record = self.env['dailycharges'].search([('billstatus', '=', record['id']), ('status', '=', 'B')], order='read_date DESC', limit=1)
# read_date = record.read_date
```

***Edit:***
You can use the `search_read` method which allow you to specify the fields to read.

Odoo provides a `search_read()` shortcut which as its name suggests is equivalent to a [search()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.search) followed by a [read()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.read), but avoids having to perform two requests and keep ids around.

Its arguments are similar to [search()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.search)’s, but it can also take a list of `fields` (like [read()](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.read), if that list is not provided it will fetch all fields of matched records)

***Example:***

```
self.env['dailycharges'].search_read([('billstatus', '=', record['id']), ('status', '=', 'B')], ['read_date'], order='read_date DESC', limit=1)

[{'id': ?, 'read_date': ?}]
```

Comment: But are we fetching only read_date column alone?  If yes,  where are we mentioning it.

Comment: The search method will return a recordset, you can access all fields with dot notation.check my edit